# adding more than 1 value in textboxfor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to get a full address in a textboxfor.

my html text box:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "col-md-1" })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address, 5, 20, new { @id= "address" })
</div>
```

Now in javascript i call :

```
 $('#address').val(data.Result.Address1);
```

this works and shows :

Jamie Road

Now i have another 2 fields which is part of address and i would want it showing in the same textboxfor:

Address2 = Manchester

Address3 = M16 9AA

I Have tried:

```
 $('#address').val(data.Result.Address1 && data.Result.Address2);
```

But this just returns Address 2.

is there a way to return address 1, 2 and 3 from the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. use `+` operator instead of `&&`:

```
$('#address').val(data.Result.Address1 + data.Result.Address2);
```

You can also add spaces and comma in between the address details to make it more readable:

```
$('#address').val(data.Result.Address1 + " " + data.Result.Address2);
```

Comment: @Andrei: a space or comma.

Comment: thanks that worked, il add <br/> to move it to next line

Comment: @mali: you should use `\n` instead.